# check and uncheck not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is causing the trouble..., I am using an existing code from stackoverflow itself but i am not sure what is causing it to break, i can see the alert, but i am unable to do the check all/uncheck all functionality, might be I am missing something here

Here is my Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkallmails" class="mail-checkbox mail-group-checkbox">

<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="9" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="10" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="11" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="12" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox">


$(document).on("#checkallmails","click", function() {
        var alls = $(this);
        console.log(alls);
        $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", alls.prop("checked"));
        });
    });
```

the above is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the syntax should be:

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

Change:

```
$(document).on("#checkallmails","click", function() {
```

To:

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkallmails", function() {
```

But it doesn't seem you need to delegate the event, also the `each` call is not necessary, `prop` iterates through the collection behind the scenes:

```
$('#checkallmails').on("change", function() {
   $('input:checkbox.mail-checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct jQuery Code -

```
$('#checkallmails').on("click", function() {
        var alls = $(this);
        console.log(alls);
        $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", alls.prop("checked"));
        });
    });
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/ss2uv8rb/

Also, "on" is not required for the code snippet you have in your question since not any element is generating dynamically. You can simply use -

```
$('#checkallmails').click(function() {
//your code
});
```

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/gL5dg6ut/

Comment: @AsadAliKanwal Loop is there in the code snippet given in the question. The issue was to check all/uncheck all functionality. Answer of which I have provided.

Comment: you are the expert, and you should have mentioned this while giving the answer. Otherwise he will use the long looped method which is bad.

Comment: @AsadAliKanwal Sir, check the fiddle you have provided. It also has loop. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mistake in the `on()` implementation, you can simplify it to

```js
//use event delegation only if it is necessory
//also use change event
$(document).on("change", "#checkallmails", function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkallmails" class="mail-checkbox mail-group-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="9" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="10" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="11" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" title="inbox_mails" id="12" name="inboxmails" class="mail-checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are we using loop?? Using unnecessary loop is bad, as it makes the code very much heavy.

Here is my code, which is very simple and light weighted

js:

```
$(document).on("click","#checkallmails", function() {
        var alls = $(this);
        console.log(alls);
        $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", alls.prop("checked"));
    });
```

See the example : http://jsfiddle.net/asadalikanwal/exgby2pf/1/